# Swift animations appear to be working in reverse

Tags: animation, swift2, ios9

I'm very new to iOS/xcode development, I'm trying to do something very basic as part of a tutorial exercise which is to fade a UILabel in once a user has completed a game.

So I'm hiding the label when the view loads:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    winMessageLabel.alpha = 0
}
```

And then on completion of the game I'm trying to fade it back in:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
     self.winMessageLabel.alpha = 1
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

But rather than fade in it appears with alpha 1 and then fades out. I get the same behaviour if I try to animate the x/y coordinates whereby it jumps to where I want it to go and then animates back to its original position

Answer (score 0):

I've just worked it out - the layout is invalid so if I call layoutIfNeeded() prior to my animation it sorts everything out and then the label animates as expected:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
     self.winMessageLabel.alpha = 1
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```